# Existence of finite nontrivial prime ideal in infinite commutative ring with unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be infinite commutative ring with unity
and $I$ be finite prime ideal of $R$
I want to know if $I$ must be trivial?

I can prove it if we further assume $R$ is integral domain

Proof:
Since $I$ is nontrivial,
$\exists a \in I$ such that $a \ne 0$
Since R is infinite,
we can pick distinct $r_1$, $r_2, \dots \in R$
Now $\{r_i a \mid i \in \mathbb{N}\} \subseteq I$
Since $I$ is finite, $\{r_i a \mid i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is also finite
So $\exists r_i, r_j \in R$ with $r_i \ne r_j$
such that $r_i a = r_j a$
Hence $(r_i - r_j) a = 0$
Since R is integral domain and $a \ne 0$,
$r_i = r_j$
Contradiction, $I$ is trivial

I want to know if this is true in the general case?

Comment: Consider $R = \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_n$.

Comment: Thank you, so $<(0, 2)>$ is a counterexample, right?

Comment: That depends on whether $n$ is odd or even. $\{0\}\times \mathbb{Z}_n$ is the example. If $n$ is even then $R/\langle(0,2)\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is not an integral domain.